# Drupal 7 Views Exposed Filters

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-exposed-filter

I using D7 on host. I created a view and i added filter(Term ID with depth). But i cant select any term. I cant see expose form (dropdown menu). D7 views exposed filter not same with D6 views exposed filter. I am sorry my English is not good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using: Content: Has Taxonomy term, and type the term(s) you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug here. Here is a solution :

1. Add your filter and save. Save also the view.
2. Come back into the view's config,
3. Click on the filter to modify and it's magical !

The terms to select appears :)

Answer (score 0):

In "Advanced" section in the view edition interface did you check "Use ajax" ? I believe you need this to see your exposed filter. It did the trick for me a couple of times.